# Tag score not updated

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-score

In my profile, the score for the Angular tag has not been updated for at least two days. It has not been updated in the Angular top users list either.

Many other users has noticed this issue also for other tags.

January 19, 2021 appears to be the last day that tag scores were updated. For one user (Ryan Cogswell) in the comments, the difference can be seen by comparing to query results on data.stackexchange.com (updated weekly). The current (as of January 25, 2021) results of [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1362792/tag-score-for-user-and-tag?tagName=reactjs&UserId=7495930) show a reactjs score of 2721, but hovering over the [2.7k in reactjs Top Answerers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reactjs/topusers) shows a score of 2695. This 26 vote difference can be accounted for by the [26 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7495930/ryan-cogswell?tab=reputation) on January 20-23 that are missing from the Top Answerers hover. There have been more upvotes since Jan 23, but those are not yet included in data.stackexchange.com since it is only updated weekly.

Comment: I also noticed the same since 3 days, it seems there is a bug

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Interesting: people upvote your comment which says that it appears to be an actual bug, but the question itself gets more downvotes.

Comment: @ConnorsFan You're aware that it's impossible to downvote a comment, right? :) However, your post is very brief. You have information in a comment, that you've not added to your post. Perhaps if you added in how much you expect one of your tags to have increased, it would appear to be more.. complete. The lack of information is probably also why this post is now closed.

Comment: @Scratte - All they need to know is in the post. StackOverflow can ignore the bug if they want. It is not a problem for me.

Comment: Huh, there might be a problem. I was wondering how is it possible that I have net 0 change in my tag scores for the past few days.

Comment: Another update time has come and gone and my tag scores haven't updated again.

Comment: I agree, I'm also facing the same issue. Is it possible a rule change? like once a week update, or is it a bug?

Comment: January 19, 2021 appears to be the last day for which the upvotes are included in my current tag scores. [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1362792/tag-score-for-user-and-tag?tagName=reactjs&UserId=7495930) shows a reactjs score of 2721, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reactjs/topusers) hovering over my score shows 2695 and I have 26 upvotes between Jan 20 and Jan 23.

Comment: Why do people downvote? It seems pretty clear that something is not right.

Comment: @mzjn - The question was closed just after I posted it, and had several downvotes.

Comment: @mzjn I suspect the downvotes were primarily due to a lack of details in the question text. I have tried to remedy that.

Comment: I've found the issue and am working on a fix for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be resolved. Lots more details on what happened and why are available [on this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360040/164200).

Comment: My Angular score appears to be up to date now. Thanks!